# How to properly extract get variables

Tags: php, html, url, variables, get

I am still somewhat new to php and was wondering the best way to extract a `$_GET` variable from a url.

for example how would I capture it out of something like this:

```
http://www.blahblahblah.com/reset_password.php?token=3072420e7e32cbcf304da791537d757342cf5957
```

just want to get everything from the "`token=etc`..."

thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An easy way:

```
$token = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : null;
```

If `token` is set it is assigned to `$token`, otherwise `$token` is null.

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET` is an array:

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

So if you print out, you should see the token part of the query string:

```
echo "'Token: $token'"; // should display 'Token: 3072420e7e32cbcf304da791537d757342cf5957';
```

**NOTE**

If you are trying to use $token to search a mysql database, you need to first escape slashes, to prevent security issues:

```
$token = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['token']);
```

Also, you first need to have a mysql connection before calling [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

**NOTE V.2**

In your query string, your token will be everything from `?token=` until PHP encounters a query key/pair delimiter (typically, `&` and `;`). To wit:

```
http://www.blahblahblah.com/reset_password.php?token=3072420e7e32cbcf304da791537d757342cf5957&token2=otherstuff
```

`&token2=otherstuff` would be another key accessible by `$_GET['token2']`, so it wouldn't be an issue with `$_GET['token']`.

Comment: that is what I have been trying but it yields nothing

Comment: You need to post the code you're using then. This is how the $_GET array works.

Answer (score 1):

So you do actually have an URL **string**, and want to *extract* values from that:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/reset_pw.php?token=3072420e7e32cbc...";

$p = parse_url($url);          // splits up the url parts
parse_str($p["query"], $get);  // breaks up individual ?var= &vars=

print $get["token"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
$token = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : null;
```

Here if the variable is not set.It returns a null

**Solution 2 :**

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```